# How to make grid element 100% available height in flex column parent?

Tags: html, css

I have this html structure:

[image]

I want to make .SceneWithHistory-Container to have 100% of available height in parent. Here is my css:

```
.Module-Container
  margin-top: 120px
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  height: 300px

.Funnel-Container
  display: grid
  grid-template-columns: 1fr
  grid-gap: 16px

.SceneWithHistory-Container
  position: relative
  display: grid
  grid-template-columns: minmax(450px, 532px) 1fr
  margin-left: -16px
  width: calc(100% + 32px)
  flex: 1

.Module-SubmitFormButtons
  background: #fff
  height: 64px
  bottom: 0
  width: calc(100% + 32px)
  margin-left: -16px
  padding: 0px 16px
  border-top: 0
  box-shadow: var(--whiteBoxShadow)
  display: flex
  align-items: center
  margin-top: 0 !important
  flex-shrink: 0
```

I'v tried to make `SceneWithHistory-Container flex: 1`, but i'ts not getting 100% of available height. If my container `.Moudule-Container` has 300px of height, i want to make `.SceneWithHistory-Container 300px - height of Funnel-Container and - Module-SubmitFormButtons.`

Please don't ask me to add `height: calc()` prop, because i want to have dynamic calculation in my parent, that's not depend of children

Answer (score 0):

flex-grow makes an element inside a flexbox use all available space.
So
`flex: 1`
should work.
I tested your code and it seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/w5uLf4s6/4/
Or isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between a greed element and any other block element in terms of setting height, and as long as it is a flex item and it's container has column direction and you've set flex: 1 so flex-grow is 1 and it should fill the remaining height as it is, and you can check it in the below snippet.

.Module-Container has a red border and .SceneWithHistory-Container has a green border.

```css
.Module-Container {
  margin-top: 120px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.Funnel-Container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  border: 5px solid green;
}

.SceneWithHistory-Container {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(450px, 532px) 1fr;
  margin-left: -16px;
  width: calc(100% + 32px);
  flex: 1;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.Module-SubmitFormButtons {
  background: #fff;
  height: 64px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: calc(100% + 32px);
  margin-left: -16px;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  border-top: 0;
  box-shadow: var(--whiteBoxShadow);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: 5px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="Module-Container">
<div class="Funnel-Container">Funnel</div>
<div class="SceneWithHistory-Container">SceneWithHistory</div>
<div class="Module-SubmitFormButtons">Module-SubmitFormButtons</div>
</div>
```